# Почему stof округляет значение до целых?

Tags: c++

В файле запись Percent:0.500 код ниже выводит 0. Как сделать так чтобы stof() не округляло число? line = 0.500, а stof(line) = 0

```
std::wifstream file(file_name);
if (!file) {
    printf("ERROR File Not Found\n");
    return false;
}

for (int i = 0; std::getline(file, line); i++) {
    if ((pos = line.find(':')) != std::wstring::npos) {

        line.erase(0, pos + 1);

        float prc = std::stof(line);

        printf("Percent:%.2f line:%ls\n", prc, line);

      //printf Percent:0 line:0.500

    }
}
```

---

Разобрался если в файле поставить 0,500 то всё ок, а если 0.500 тогда округляет до 0. Почему так? как это исправить?

Comment: У вас локаль -- русский. Поставьте `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")`;

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что, скорее всего, у вас установлена русская локаль, в которой разделителем целой и дробной части в числах с плавающей точкой является не точка, а запятая.

Таким образом, функция `std::stof` читает первый символ - `0`, потом второй - `.`, который не способен формировать число с плавающей точкой, и по этой причине прекращает чтение, превращает уже прочитанные символы (`0`) в число с плавающей точкой и возвращает его.

Чтобы такого не происходило и строка преобразовывалось корректно, вам необходимо установить локаль, в которой разделителем целой и дробной части является точка, а не запятая:

```cpp
std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "POSIX");
```